# Getting Error on pushing code to cloud

Tags: magento-upgrade

I have updated the magento cloud EE version from 2.2.0 to latest but on local it works fine when i push my code to cloud then it gives me errors

i tried following command:

> composer require "magento/magento-cloud-metapackage":">=2.3.2 <2.3.3" --no-update

then,

update composer and update php version in `app.magento.yaml`

then add `composer.json` && `composer.lock` && `.app.magento.yaml` 
and commit the code and then push

after running command it gives me following errors

```
CRITICAL: The command "php ./bin/magento module:enable --all --ansi --no-interaction" failed. PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare __() (previously declared in /app/vendor/magento/framework/Phrase/__.php:15) in /app/app/functions.php on line 22  
        W: 
        W: In RefreshModules.php line 55:
        W:                                                                                
        W:   The command "php ./bin/magento module:enable --all --ansi --no-interaction"  
        W:    failed. PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare __() (previously declared in /a  
        W:   pp/vendor/magento/framework/Phrase/__.php:15) in /app/app/functions.php on   
        W:   line 22                                                                      
        W:                                                                                
        W: 
        W: In Shell.php line 86:
        W:                                                                                
        W:   The command "php ./bin/magento module:enable --all --ansi --no-interaction"  
        W:    failed. PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare __() (previously declared in /a  
        W:   pp/vendor/magento/framework/Phrase/__.php:15) in /app/app/functions.php on   
        W:   line 22                                                                      
        W:                                                                                
        W: 
        W: build
        W: 

      E: Error building project: Step failed with status code 255.
```

Please guide me as if i am running wrong commands or in solving above issues

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have an incompatible PHP Version.  You can resolve this by setting the php version in the `.magento.app.yaml` to match the minimum required per magento 2.3.x requirements.

**Here is documentation:** https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/cloud/project/project-conf-files_magento-app.html

**Here is the example:** PHP v7.2 for the latest version of cloud: https://github.com/magento/magento-cloud/blob/master/.magento.app.yaml

---

**Oct 18, 2019 Update - Solution**

I have found out that `composer upgrade` is being executed on the local system which has a PHP version of 7.1.x.  Composer packages with dependencies for PHP 7.1.x are then used and when the `composer.lock` file is created, it contains incompatibilities for PHP 7.2.x.

Since the composer.lock is used when `composer install` is executed on the remote server, it halts on conflicts with PHP Versions.

So, the solution here is to run `composer upgrade` on a system with PHP 7.2.x before you commit or upload the `composer.lock`.  If this is not possible, attempt to run `composer upgrade` on remote system.  If that is not possible, remove the composer.lock file and commit that removal.  This will use the composer.json to then install the packages using the remote system's PHP constraints.

Ultimately, you'll need to get your local PHP upgraded to 7.2.x.

Comment: I have set the php v to 7.2 and also replace the code of .magento.app.yaml file with your example code of .magento.app.yaml file but same error.

Comment: You may have done a composer upgrade on your local system with 7.1

Comment: On local i have a php v 7.1.3 so i have done upgradation on local with this version

Comment: You can't create a composer.lock (from running composer update) on a system with PHP 7.1.x and then run composer install on a system with PHP 7.2.x.
This is 100% the issue and it can be resolved by running `composer update` under php 7.2.x and then committing the composer.lock where it will run `composer install` on a system with php 7.2.x.

Answer (score 0):

Install the Yireo Replace Inventory module https://github.com/yireo/magento2-replace-inventory (composer require yireo/magento2-replace-inventory:2.3.*), run composer install and bin/magento setup:upgrade.  Then push your changes to trigger a rebuild.  That worked for me.